# Looking for an old anime about two (android?) girls in search of a heart

Tags: mahoromatic

I remember the anime series revolving around two girls, an older and a younger one. The younger one was some kind of android of sorts and she was sad because she wanted a heart.

The girls were both dressed as maids and the younger girl had short orange hair.

It was an older anime for sure, I must have watched it around late 90's or early 00's.

At the end of the anime, the younger android girl went into some kind of facility, probably a government facility, for some reason.

I vividly remember the ending being a bit violent, the older girl (I think she was an android too but with a heart) came to save the younger girl and they were falling down a huge circular pit type thing while being shot at.

I am pretty sure they survived but I cannot remember the name!

Comment: Do you remember how the girls looked like? hair/eye color, age, any traits? Did the animation looked old or newish?

Comment: I love how this post was edited by 5 different people in the last 10 minutes, just to get the spelling and layout right.

Comment: Are you looking for an anime movie or series?

Comment: The girls were dressed as maids am pretty sure! Also, it is an anime series. The young girl had short orangish hair. Was for sure older animation, around late 90's and early 00's x.x and sorry for the typos and bad layout

Answer (score 11):

[image]

This sounds like [Mahoromatic 2](http://myanimelist.net/anime/277/Mahoromatic_2) (Something more beautiful), the second season of the series which involves battle androids (dressed as Maids in the case of these 2) and spans 14 episodes.

From the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahoromatic) for Minawa, the orange-haired younger android:

> Minawa is first introduced in Mahoromatic ~Something More Beautiful~. Clumsy and anemic, she ends up living with Mahoro and Suguru and going to school under the pretext of being Mahoro's younger sister. She has a habit of apologizing for everything she does, even if she has done nothing wrong. She claims to be a runaway member of The Management, but is later revealed to have been sent to gather information on VESPER's battle android Mahoro after being promised a heart in return. Mahoro, however, convinces her that the fact that she can cry means she already has a heart.

The original series aired in 2001, but the one with Minawa, the orange-haired girl aired in 2002. The first series didn't have Minawa in it.

Episode 10:

> Where the enemy android from The Management tells Minawa that it's time for her to hold up her end of the bargain, so she kidnaps Suguru (the male lead) and takes him to the laboratory (where the large cylindrical room is). Mahoro comes to save him but is captured, then Minawa has a change of heart and frees everyone but gets shot in the process.
> [image]
> Mahoro then goes crazy and destroys everything
> [image]
> And the episode ends in a huge fire fight (looking down into the bottom of the cylindrical room which is on fire)
> [image]

The ending of the 2nd season:

> Is pretty violent as a culmination of both Mahoro's lifespan ending and the final battle. It's also pretty sad as well as controversial for an ending.